# What happened underlying during creating shared library?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I use windows, and I have 100 static libraries in my project, and the size of each of them is about 10MB. I named those 100 libraries as below:

```
lib1.lib
lib2.lib
...
lib100.lib
```

I use command `link.exe /OUT:sum.dll lib1.lib lib2.lib ... lib100.lib /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /PDB:"D:/path/to/sum.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"D:/path/to/sum.lib" /MACHINE:X64  /machine:x64 /IGNORE:4006 /IGNORE:4098 /IGNORE:4217 /IGNORE:4221 /DLL` to build shared library in release mode.

I got `sum.dll` with size about 50MB.

Then I use command `lib.exe /OUT:libsum.lib lib1.lib lib2.lib ... lib100.lib` to build static library in release mode.

I got `libsum.lib` with size about 1000MB.

I know that static library simply zip all the libs related. But why the size of `libsum.lib` is much bigger than `sum.dll`? What happened underlying during building `sum.dll`?

Comment: What's the size of sum.pdb?

Comment: The dll will throw away functions and data that are not used. The static library has to keep everything because you link the static library to other dlls and executables that may or may not need the functions and data.

Comment: There is no sum.pdb in Release mode. @ssbssa

Comment: Your used command has `/PDB:"D:/path/to/sum.pdb"`, so I assumed sum.pdb is also created.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the reason why the dll will throw away functions and data that are not used? When I build dll, programs using this dll are undetermined. @drescherjm

Comment: A dll has a public interface defined by what symbols you export from the dll. If there is no way to access a function from the public interface it can be eliminated. The only way for other programs or dlls to use the dll is to call exported functions in the public interface

Comment: I still cannot get your point, can you share with me some links or materials concerning the content of dll? Thank you so much! @drescherjm

Comment: With DLLs, symbols are private by default. Everything that's not explicitly exported or reachable through a public export is discarded by the linker. And Microsoft's linker just happens to be very good at identifying unreachable symbols. If that is not what you want, choose a toolchain like MinGW that marks all symbols public by default.